# angular rxjs observable inside ngIf-block miss first update

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-template

I have two observables. First observable is used for ngIf-Block Statement.
Second observable is used inside the ngIf-Block and maps values from first observable.

The second observable do not get the *first* update from source inside the ngIf-Block.
On otherhand, outside of ngIf-Block it works.

Any explanations for this unexpected behavior?

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-template-update-problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because `number$` is Subject and it's used inside `*ngIf` which means it subscribes to `sum$` only after this template block is created and that happens after `sum$` is updated with `this.number$.next(1)`.

So what you can do is using `ReplaySubject(1)` instead that will replay its latest item to every new subscriber so when the template `async` pipe inside `*ngIf` subscribes to it it gets the last value replayd and updates as you expect.

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-template-update-problem-xb5f3s?file=src/app/app.component.ts